# Amazon Route 53 Domain Name, linking to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have purchased a domain (deepalgorithm.net), however I am a bit curious as to how I would route all traffic that visit this domain to my Amazon Elastic BeanStalk instance, which is running my web application.

Secondly, how can I make it so that , when users type this link "deepalgorithm.net" it takes them to my web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put Elastic Load Balancer in front of your application and point record in Route53 to the ELB

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you got the domian in Route53, there is an entire section in the **AWS docs** devoted to setting up the routing:

- [Routing traffic to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html)

The process involves creating a **Route 53 record** to your EB domain:

- [Creating an Amazon Route 53 record that routes traffic to your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-resource-record-set)